# notionistic education / teaching?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What's the right word to indicate a type of education based on memorizing facts or a superficial understanding of things, without real insight or critical mind development?

In my native language (Italian) we have expressions like "nozionismo" or "educazione nozionistica" or "didattica nozionistica". But, after I looked in the dictionary, it seems to me that the word "notion" in this case is a "false friend". In fact, "nozione" seems different from "notion", which is rather like an opinion.

Comment: For a model that puts such cognitive-domain objectives firmly in their place (as being elementary and insufficient, though still very necessary), see the article on **Bloom's Taxonomy** (daft name) at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom's_Taxonomy .

Comment: Learning by heart, drill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The English word for the kind of education you describe is "[rote](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rote)" learning.

Comment: Also "indoctrination, re-education," and "treatment", among other euphemisms.

Answer (score 0):

"Drill and Kill" teaching method . For reference , check this http://www.nychold.com/hirsch-termin.html#drill

Answer (score 0):

It does not cover the full semantics of "nozionismo" but could *mechanical learning* be an alternative? (I'm just intuitively suggesting it as I'm not an English native speaker, please correct me if I am wrong)