# word for a person who learns a lot by heart when studying

Tags: nouns

Do you happen to know a noun to describe someone, usually a student, who does a lot of learning by heart, as opposed to understanding? Is 'grind', 'swot'/'swotter' a good word for that, or does it just mean an over-the-top hard-working, diligent student? I also came acrosss 'muzz', can that be used as a noun? In Russian, we have a word 'zubrila', which means someone who stupidly learns things by heart. Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/105608/291924.

Answer (score 1):

Educationalists make a distinction between "rote learning" and "meaningful learning".

> **Rote learning** is the memorization of information based on repetition.
>   Examples of rote learning include memorizing the alphabet, numbers,
>   and multiplication tables. Some consider rote learning to be a
>   necessary step in learning certain subjects.
>
> Memorization isn’t the most effective way to learn, but it’s a method
>   many students and teachers still use. A common rote learning technique
>   is preparing quickly for a test, also known as cramming.
>
> **Meaningful learning** involves understanding how all the pieces of an
>   entire concept fit together. The knowledge gained through meaningful
>   learning applies to new learning situations. This type of learning
>   stays with students for life.
>
> Meaningful learning is active, constructive, and long-lasting, but
>   most importantly, it allows students to be fully engaged in the
>   learning process.

[Rote and meaningful learning](https://www.oxfordlearning.com/difference-rote-learning-meaningful-learning/)